# full page (one page per scroll / mouse or space bar or down/up arrow) using CSS only

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if anyone can point out a solution that can allow for one full page scroll down/up using mouse/spacebar/arrow or swipe action that uses only CSS.

There is jquery.onepage-scroll.js, jquery.fullpage.js  (which require jquery) which provide such facilities - and several examples on codepen that use jquery - but for I am trying to build a landing page - and see no reason to build in jquery if not needed.

even pointer to code that is similar will be helpful.

thanks

Comment: Using mouse? an `<a href="#someID">` should be enough

Comment: @amit - I am not asking for a link - but a response by the browser to a scroll request (or swipe request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - after some more research, I came across this article - http://blog.gospodarets.com/css-scroll-snap/ which talks about https://drafts.csswg.org/css-snappoints/#scroll-snap-type - which should give me what I need - but it is not supported well yet according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints

I guess - have to wait or use jquery. Hope some one has a different solution.

Comment: you're right.. apart from the jquery plugins - I was also not able to find something only CSS or JS that can do this.